LinkedIn: share post API returns 401 unauthorized
I want to share a post using the LinkedIn Post API.

async function shareOnLinkedin(authCode:string,accessToken: string) {
  const ME_RESOURCE = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo';
  const POSTS_RESOURCE = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts';

  const API_VERSION = '202302';

  try {
    // Fetch user profile to get user ID
    const meResponse = await fetch(ME_RESOURCE, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });

    if (!meResponse.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Error fetching profile: ${meResponse.statusText}`);
    }

    const meData = await meResponse.json();
    console.log('User profile:', meData);

    // Create a new post
    const postResponse = await axios.post(POSTS_RESOURCE, {
      //method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "author": `urn:li:person:${meData.id}`,
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "specificContent": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                "shareCommentary": {
                    "text": "Learning more about LinkedIn by reading the LinkedIn Blog!"
                },
                "shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE",
                "media": [
                    {
                        "status": "READY",
                        "description": {
                            "text": "Official LinkedIn Blog - Your source for insights and information about LinkedIn."
                        },
                        "originalUrl": "https://blog.linkedin.com/",
                        "title": {
                            "text": "Official LinkedIn Blog"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "visibility": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
        }
      })
    });

    // if (!postResponse) {
    //   throw new Error(`Error creating post: ${postResponse.statusText}`);
    // }

    const postData = await postResponse.data();
    console.log('Post created:', postData);

    // This is the created share URN
    console.log('Created post ID:', postData.id);

  } catch (error) {
    
    console.error('Error sharing post:', error);
  }
}

I am exectuting this function from a supabase edge function.
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
      },

The token used in the header is created from the LinkedIn Developer dashboard OAuth tool.

I attempted using the 3 legged Auth flow to generate the access token but the response is still 401 unauthorized.

I attempted using the 3 legged Auth flow to generate auth code but the response is still 401 unauthorized.

I attemped using the LinkedIn API SDK but getting 426 Request failed



async function shareOnLinkedinOld(authCode:string,accessToken: string){
  const ME_RESOURCE = '/userinfo';
  const UGC_POSTS_RESOURCE = '/ugcPosts';
  const POSTS_RESOURCE = '/posts';
  const API_VERSION = '202302';

  const restliClient = new RestliClient();
  restliClient.setDebugParams({ enabled: true });
 

  const meResponse = await restliClient.get({
    resourcePath: ME_RESOURCE,
    accessToken
  });

  console.log(meResponse.data);
  const postsCreateResponse = await restliClient.create({
    resourcePath: UGC_POSTS_RESOURCE,
    entity: {
      author: `urn:li:person:${meResponse.data.id}`,
      lifecycleState: 'PUBLISHED',
      visibility: 'PUBLIC',
      commentary: 'Sample text post created with /posts API',
      distribution: {
        feedDistribution: 'MAIN_FEED',
        targetEntities: [],
        thirdPartyDistributionChannels: []
      }
    },
    accessToken:accessToken,
    versionString: API_VERSION
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error Sharing Post:', error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error if you want to handle it later
  });
  // This is the created share URN
  console.log(postsCreateResponse.createdEntityId);
}

I have validated the access Token on the OAuth  Tools on the developer dashboard. The access Token is active and not expired.
What could i be doing wrong?

The 426 error occurred because the versionString parameter from the GitHub example triggered a call to an outdated API. Since it is optional, I removed it. I also corrected the author field to use the correct person URN, and changed the resource endpoint to /posts instead of /ugcPosts.
The correct function appears as
async function shareOnLinkedin(accessToken: string){
  const ME_RESOURCE = '/userinfo';
  const POSTS_RESOURCE = '/posts';


  const restliClient = new RestliClient();
  restliClient.setDebugParams({ enabled: true });
 
  const meResponse = await restliClient.get({
    resourcePath: ME_RESOURCE,
    accessToken
  });
  const postsCreateResponse = await restliClient.create({
    resourcePath: POSTS_RESOURCE,
    entity: {
      "author": `urn:li:person:${meResponse.data.sub}`,
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "specificContent": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                "shareCommentary": {
                    "text": "Learning more about LinkedIn by reading the LinkedIn Blog!"
                },
                "shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE",
                "media": [
                    {
                        "status": "READY",
                        "description": {
                            "text": "Official LinkedIn Blog - Your source for insights and information about LinkedIn."
                        },
                        "originalUrl": "https://blog.linkedin.com/",
                        "title": {
                            "text": "Official LinkedIn Blog"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "visibility": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
        }
    },
    accessToken:accessToken
    //versionString: API_VERSION
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error Sharing Post:', error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error if you want to handle it later
  });
  // This is the created share URN
  console.log(postsCreateResponse.createdEntityId);
  return postsCreateResponse.createdEntityId
}

